# Joomla Site is too slow on Firefox, but normal on other browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, joomla, joomla2.5

I have this site http://consyn.com/ in Joomla 2.5

I am having big trouble figuring out that why this site is too slow to load in Firefox, everytime browser hangs for 2 or seconds then loads it.

It loads normally in Google Chrome.

I have tried disabling Maps on the homepage but it has no affect.

Can someone suggest me what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

As i analyze your problem in Firefox each and every website before the load not apply the style(css,js etc..)
but the other browser applied it that's why this website hang in Firefox but not other at starting time.

As you mention in your Question in chrome this website not load but after some time its also load in my computer.

As a solution in your Joomla 2.5 anywhere you search

```
QuotaService.RecordEvent
```

named javascript file are there and that is the problem,this file always send to request to something get,actually that which type of data always want that i can't locate but you search this file and check your code and change it.

Comment: Sorry but your answer is not much helpful

Comment: in short and simple language above given files are repeatedly wait for some data but data not retrieve so that browser hang or crash the page.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh ... which given file takes more time??? you mentioned alllll JS CSS files ...